# Strange issue with static const member variable changing value

Tags: c++, class, static, constants, visual-studio-debugging

Suppose I have a class with a static const member variable:

```
// foo.h
class foo {
public:
   foo(){}
   bool greaterThan(int someNum){return num > someNum}
private:
   static const int num;
};

// foo.cpp
const int foo::num = 321;
```

If I debug this in Visual Studio 2013 something odd is happening for me; the debugger states that num is 1, even though the code is executing with the correct value; Any ideas of what may cause this?

Comment: Do you have all of this code in the same file?

Comment: Also you shouldn't have bool foo() in class foo

Comment: The actual class is much larger, but this small example isolates the issue I am having. Using separate files, header and cpp; In my actual program, num is being initialized in the cpp.

Comment: @Eric bool foo() was an accident, updated question.

Comment: @Alex Mardikian As there is no relevant code that can reproduces the problem I think that the question should be closed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: So you would rather have mountains of code dumped on you, or deny the existence of hard to reproduce questions?

Comment: Fixed the issue with my function not working correctly, there was a different underlying problem. The debugger is still falsely stating the static const is 1 regardless of the program executing with the correct value. Still baffled by this, but not going to spend any more time trying to figure out the issue with the debugger.

Comment: @Zan Lynx When you try to create the program that reproduces the problem then you usualy yourself very quicly find the error. There is no any sense to consider irrelevant code.

Comment: Why is this marked as unclear? It's clear, got an answer which tells how to find the issue - what is happening. For me it is a valid question with a valuable answer. If you start programming, you just don't know every thing there is to know - which leaves you behind the issue and so you're longing for input. It got a valid answer. For me, it gave me more insight about debugging.

Comment: @Alex: You should learn how to use the debugger correctly. It is your most valuable source of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for a static const int to change its value. Not legally. But possible anyway.

The value has a memory location and it might not be in a read-only link section. If it isn't, then a write out of bounds might change it. A write outside of an array or a string for example.

To find it, I would use the debugger to break at main() check its value to see it is 321, then set a watch on the value. When it changes you have found the bad piece of code that is doing it.